# Dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
1st Text file format . 
cake,60
cake,30
tart,50
bread,89  

2nd Text file format . 
cake,10
cake,10
tart,10
bread,10
```

Code I have tried.

```
from collections import defaultdict
answer = defaultdict(int)
recordNum = int(input("Which txt files do you want to read from "))
count = 1
counter = 0
counst = 1
countesr = 0
while recordNum > counter:
  with open('txt'+str(count)+'.txt', 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
          k, v = line.strip().split(',')
          answer[k.strip()] += int(v.strip())
          count = count+1
          counter = counter+1
print(answer)
```

The problem.

```
I want the dictionary to be {'cake': '110', 'tart': '60', 'bread': '99'}

but it prints like this  {'cake': '30', 'tart': '50', 'bread': '89'}
```

Instead of the "cake" value adding with the other cake values from txt file one and two it gets replaced with the latest value. How would I solve this issue. Also i tried to make it so if I write 3, it would open and add from 3 txt files, named, txt1.txt, txt2.txt and txt3.txt

Comment: Can't reproduce this. It works correctly for me. However it gives 110 cakes (30+60+10+10) and I hardcoded the filenames.

Comment: What do you mean by hard coding the file names??

Comment: Well, I don't like `input` so I just created two files and just iterated over them instead of your `while recordNum > counter:`.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your 2nd file doesnt get read:

```
Which txt files do you want to read from 2
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'cake': 60})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'cake': 90})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'tart': 50, 'cake': 90})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'tart': 50, 'bread': 89, 'cake': 90})
>> terminating
```

You could make these edits to read all the files (Note: this assumes your text files are named txt1.txt, txt2.txt, txt3.txt and so on..):

```
from collections import defaultdict
answer = defaultdict(int)
number_of_records = int(input("How many text files do you want to read?"))
for i in range(1, number_of_records+1):
    with open('txt{}.txt'.format(i), 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            k, v = line.strip().split(',')
            answer[k] += int(v)
print(answer)


How many text files do you want to read?
>> 2
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'bread': 99, 'tart': 60, 'cake': 110})
>> terminating
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if the code is pythonic way, but works for me and is hardcoded.

```
x={}
y={}
with open("a.txt") as file:
    for i in file:
        (key, val) = i.split(',')
        if key in x.keys(): x[key]=x[key]+int(val.rstrip())
        else: x[key] = int(val.rstrip())

with open("b.txt") as file:
    for i in file:
        (key, val) = i.split(',')
        if key in y.keys(): y[key]=y[key]+int(val.rstrip())
        else: y[key] = int(val.rstrip())

print { k: x.get(k, 0) + y.get(k, 0) for k in set(x) | set(y) }
```

This may help you :
[Merge and sum of two dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461531/merge-and-sum-of-two-dictionaries)