# combine values in a list of dicts containing a list of dicts

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

This is way out of my comfort range and I'm not even sure I can describe it well enough.  I have a file that is a list of dicts that contain another list of dicts.  An excerpt of the data structure is below:

```
j_traffic =
[   
    {
    "timePeriod":   "2017-08-04T15:20:00.000+0000",
    "applicationTrafficPerApplication": [
         {
         "applicationId":   39,
         "applicationName": "HTTP",
         "trafficInboundBps":   148760,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  5673493,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         },
         {
         "applicationId":   41,
         "applicationName": "HTTPS",
         "trafficInboundBps":   16805,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  546937,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         }
         ]
    },
    {
    "timePeriod":   "2017-08-04T15:15:00.000+0000",
    "applicationTrafficPerApplication": [
         {
         "applicationId":   39,
         "applicationName": "HTTP",
         "trafficInboundBps":   157569,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  5769206,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         },
         {
         "applicationId":   41,
         "applicationName": "HTTPS",
         "trafficInboundBps":   17454,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  590421,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         },
         {
         "applicationId":   44,
         "applicationName": "DNS",
         "trafficInboundBps":   18218,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  13683,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         },
         {
         "applicationId":   45,
         "applicationName": "SNMP",
         "trafficInboundBps":   14,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  0,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         }  
         ]
    },  
    {   
    "timePeriod":   "2017-08-04T15:05:00.000+0000",
    "applicationTrafficPerApplication": [
         {  
         "applicationId":   39,
         "applicationName": "HTTP",
         "trafficInboundBps":   139897,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  5073320,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         }, 
         {  
         "applicationId":   41,
         "applicationName": "HTTPS",
         "trafficInboundBps":   22592,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  457962,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         }, 
         {  
         "applicationId":   44,
         "applicationName": "DNS",
         "trafficInboundBps":   19903,
         "trafficOutboundBps":  14033,
         "trafficWithinBps":    0
         }
         ]
    }
]
```

I am trying to understand how I can create a new dict using "applicationName" value as the keys and the values are the sum of all values of key "trafficInboundBps" that would look like this:

inboundTraffic = {"HTTP": 446316, "HTTPS": 56581, "DNS": 38121, "SNMP": 14}

I've tried suggestions I found on here but can't wrap my head around how to parse the nested levels with the following:
inboundTraffic = dict.fromkeys(set().union(*j_traffic))

Any takers?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plain and simple code for processing the j_traffic list and getting the expected output.

```
output = dict()
# iterate over the list of outer dicts
for outer_dict in j_traffic:
    # grab the list assigned to key applicationTrafficPerApplication
    application_traffic_per_application = outer_dict['applicationTrafficPerApplication']
    # iterate over the list of inner dicts
    for inner_dict in application_traffic_per_application:
        application_name = inner_dict['applicationName']
        traffic_inbound_bps = inner_dict['trafficInboundBps']
        if application_name in output:
            output[application_name] += int(traffic_inbound_bps)
        else:
            output[application_name] = int(traffic_inbound_bps)

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility to do what you're asking:

```
# Extract outer dictionaries as a list
lst = [s["applicationTrafficPerApplication"] for s in j_traffic]

# Turn first element of lst into a dictionary 
inboundTraffic={s2["applicationName"]: s2["trafficInboundBps"] for s2 in lst[0]}
# Process remaining elements - combine and add
for comp in lst[1:]:
    temp = {s2["applicationName"]: s2["trafficInboundBps"] for s2 in comp}
    # This turns both dictionaries into sets, selects all elements 
    # (I assume that's why it's using sets - to have access to all), 
    # then adds the resepective elements - 0 in .get(k,0) signifies that
    # "0" will be added if particular element doesn't exist in the second set/dictionary
    inboundTraffic = {k: inboundTraffic.get(k,0) + temp.get(k,0) for k in set(inboundTraffic) | set(temp)} 

print inboundTraffic
```

I'm still learning the pythonic ways of doing things so I bet there is a shorter and more proper solution - but this indeed does the trick.

The last line in the for loop was due to this post [Merge and sum of two dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461531/merge-and-sum-of-two-dictionaries).

Do you want your output sorted?