# How to add up the same 'items' in a dictionary of multiple dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How could I add up the speed of these characters even if they don't all have the attribute speed? This is an example, there are many other attributes. The characters are picked randomly and grouped together:

```
character_1 = {'Money': .3, 'Strength': .25, 'Speed': .05}
character_2 = {'Money': .3, 'Age': 25, 'Speed': .7}
character_3 = {'Money': .3, 'Strength': .25, 'Power': 5}
```

How could I find out the combined speed, money, age etc of all these characters? (if age is not defined for others the right answer should be 25 years in total)
thank you!!

Comment: What you actually want to do is merge your two dictionaries, and that's already been answered on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461531/merge-and-sum-of-two-dictionaries#10461916) (third line of the correct answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge and sum of two dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461531/merge-and-sum-of-two-dictionaries)

Comment: Actually you need to rethink your whole structure. You shouldn't create variable like that but create classes, use a database or nest them inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through a `list` of the `dicts` and combine their `values` in a result `dict` like this:

```
character_1 = {'Money': .3, 'Strength': .25, 'Speed': .05}
character_2 = {'Money': .3, 'Age': 25, 'Speed': .7}
character_3 = {'Money': .3, 'Strength': .25, 'Power': 5}

dict_list = [character_1, character_2, character_3]

result = dict()

for d in dict_list:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in result:
            result[k] += v
        else:
            result[k] = v

print(result)

{'Money': 0.8999999999999999, 'Strength': 0.5, 'Speed': 0.75, 'Age': 25, 'Power': 5}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) . You could implement your characters as float defaultdicts, which gives them a `0.0` for any item that hasn't been set yet:

```
from collections import defaultdict

character = defaultdict(float)
```

So now any first item retrieval will initialize the value with zero if it hasn't been written before:

```
In [7]: character["Money"]
Out[7]: 0.0

In [8]: character["Speed"]
Out[8]: 0.0
```

This approach has its drawbacks for certain applications, though. Like when not all values in the dict are of numeric type, or have a different initial value. In this case, a `class` might be the only choice you've got, as @Anton vBR pointed out.