# pandas groupby column to sum the Counter performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, something like:

```
index     name     message_counter
1         AA       Counter({'hello':1})
2         BB       Counter({'how':1, 'are':1, 'you':1})
3         BB       Counter({'how':1})
4         AA       Counter({'hello':1})
5         CC       Counter({'hello':1})
```

I want a sum of all the counters from each unique name.
So I did:

```
df.groupby('name')['message_counter'].sum()
```

and got the right answer. something like:

```
name
AA            {'hello':2}
BB            {'how':2, 'are':1, 'you':1}
CC            {'hello':1}
```

But it was surprisingly slow on my data set. It's going through 6 unique names and summing through 33,000 Counters (numbers of rows in my data frame), Which is not that much, but it took me way longer than I expected. Something like 50+ seconds, and the whole 180 lines doesn't take that much time.

What am I doing wrong? How can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use a bit improved [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461952):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dsum(*dicts):
    ret = defaultdict(int)
    #add loop for Series of dicts
    for x in dicts:
        for d in x:
            for k, v in d.items():
                ret[k] += v
    return dict(ret)

df1 = df.groupby('name')['message_counter'].agg(dsum)
```

Comment: Wow yeah is performs a lot better. Any idea why?

Comment: @sheldonzy - In my opinion `pandas` working not very fast with non scalar values, because primary it dont supports (some function should also failed), so better is use pure python.